# equivalent to numpy.linalg.lstsq that allows weighting

Tags: python, numpy

I am fitting a 2d polynomial with the numpy function linalg.lstsq:

```
coeffs = np.array([y*0+1, y, x, x**2, y**2]).T
coeff_r, r, rank, s =np.linalg.lstsq(coeffs, values)
```

Some points that I am trying to fit are more reliable than others.
Is there a way to weigh the points differently?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lstsq` is enough for this; the weights can be applied to the equations. That is, if in an overdetermined system

```
3*a + 2*b = 9
2*a + 3*b = 4
5*a - 4*b = 2
```

you care about the first equation more than about the others, multiply it by some number greater than 1. For example, by 5:

```
15*a + 10*b = 45
2*a + 3*b = 4
5*a - 4*b = 2
```

Mathematically, the system is the same, but the least squares solution will be different because it minimizes the sum of squares of the residuals, and the residual of the 1st equation got multiplied by 5.

Here is an example based on your code (with small adjustments to make it more NumPythonic). First, unweighted fit:

```
import numpy as np
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 3), np.arange(0, 3))
x = x.ravel()
y = y.ravel()
values = np.sqrt(x+y+2)   # some values to fit
functions = np.stack([np.ones_like(y), y, x, x**2, y**2], axis=1)
coeff_r = np.linalg.lstsq(functions, values, rcond=None)[0]
values_r = functions.dot(coeff_r)
print(values_r - values)
```

This displays the residuals as

```
[ 0.03885814 -0.00502763 -0.03383051 -0.00502763  0.00097465  0.00405298
 -0.03383051  0.00405298  0.02977753]
```

Now I give the 1st data point greater weight.

```
weights = np.ones_like(x)
weights[0] = 5
coeff_r = np.linalg.lstsq(functions*weights[:, None], values*weights, rcond=None)[0]
values_r = functions.dot(coeff_r)
print(values_r - values)
```

Residuals:

```
[ 0.00271103 -0.01948647 -0.04828936 -0.01948647  0.00820407  0.0112824
 -0.04828936  0.0112824   0.03700695]
```

The first residual is now an order of magnitude smaller, of course at the expense of others residuals.